# Mysql: 2 tables with unique ID

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables in phpmyadmin

1. Clients
2. Companies

   ```
   id,TYPE, Name, Surname, birthDate, city
   ```

   **1, CLIENT, Barack, Obama, 11.20.1980, Tokio**

   ```
   id,TYPE, Name, Capital, RegisterDate, OfficeAddress
   ```

   **1, COMPANY, Google, 500000$, 10.12.1990, MountineView**

via php i insert data in both tables, and then  they get same ID  (above example: they have both id 1)

so problem starts when showing all rows in php table (while loop)

```
 **Select * from...** "and **join** both  tables"
```

in list table i put a button that i can edit each row
ID" so how can i edit like this when in both tables id is same (example 1) (there are 2 posts with id 1 in DB )

-Is there a way to set unique ID (so both tables has unique id and numbers cant be same on both tables)
if yes, then how do i know in which table the post is

or there is another way

Comment: Does your question is "Where will you get the ID in two tables to edit?" because As far as I know, this depends on your record you want to be edited. if you are going to edit the company profile. then the ID of the company should be retrieved and vice versa. or you will edit the same table at the same time?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're really doing. What does `SELECT * from " and join 2 tables" mean? Please show the actual SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SELECT *` when both tables have columns with the same name. List the columns specifically and add aliases so you can distinguish them.

```
SELECT cl.id AS client_id, co.id AS company_id, cl.name AS client_name, co.name AS company_name, ...
FROM clients AS cl
JOIN companies AS co ON ...
```